# How does the double pointers work for a linked list implementation?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, reference

The following code works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    Node(int data, Node *next = nullptr){
        this->data = data;
        this->next = next;
    }
};

void push_back(Node **head, int data){
    if(*head == nullptr){
        *head = new Node(data);
    }
    else{
        Node *current = *head;
        while(current->next != nullptr){
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = new Node(data);
    }
}


void Print(Node **head){
    Node *current = *head;
    while(current != nullptr){
        cout << current->data << " ";
        current = current->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    Node *head = nullptr;
    push_back(&head, 5);
    push_back(&head, 2);
    push_back(&head, 1);
    push_back(&head, -7);
    Print(&head);

}
```

But when I try that bellow, nothing happens and head remains nullptr along with all the operations.
All I did was that I passed single pointers to function instead of double pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    Node(int data, Node *next = nullptr){
        this->data = data;
        this->next = next;
    }
};

void push_back(Node *head, int data){
    if(head == nullptr){
        head = new Node(data);
    }
    else{
        Node *current = head;
        while(current->next != nullptr){
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = new Node(data);
    }
}


void Print(Node *head){
    Node *current = head;
    while(current != nullptr){
        cout << current->data << " ";
        current = current->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    Node *head = nullptr;
    push_back(head, 5);
    push_back(head, 2);
    push_back(head, 1);
    push_back(head, -7);
    Print(head);

}
```

I don't understand why do I need double pointers to make it work?
Is the second program only sending a copy of head to the functions and nothing more?

Comment: Yep, that's basically all that happens. `void Print(Node *head)` has only a pointer to a single `Node`, but doesn't "know" about the variable in `main`. In C++ `void Print(Node * &head)` would be clearer than a double pointer imo.

Comment: If you want a function to modify a thing, you need to pass it a pointer (or reference) to that thing, regardless of the type of the thing. There is nothing special about things that happen to be pointers.

Comment: Since you don't want Print to modify `head` in `int main()`  you should use `void Print(Node *head){` for the functions you want to modify the head pointer in main you want to pass the pointer by reference. `void push_back(Node* &head, int data){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void push_back(Node *head, int data){
    if(head == nullptr){
        head = new Node(data);
    }
    else{
        Node *current = head;
        while(current->next != nullptr){
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = new Node(data);
    }
}
```

you can't change the value of pointer `head` by `push_back` in `main` function. We can change a object by passing its pointer or reference to another function, but not by passing itself! So each time `head = new Node(data);`(try to change `head`) actually not change `head` in the function which called `push back()` and caused memory overflow

Comment: That really helped, but is it valid only for objects, or for every type of pointer?

Comment: My pleasure. Of course every type of pointer. I'm sorry my expression was not very accurate. I'm not a native English speaker.